# Error installing SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

When Installing this error popups. And all SQL features get installed in the end except reporting services. Please any help appreciated.

> Updating permission setting for folder 'C:\Windows\Temp' failed. The folder permission setting were supposed to be set to 'D [Sad] A;OICI;0x1200af;;;S-1-5-80-4063824523-3130906261-2263067808-2545249320-213050741)'.
>   Error code: 0x84CF0003

Comment: Try  Right Click installer then choose  " Run as Administrator ".

Comment: I tried that too. Same error happened.

Comment: see this :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116641/loading-sql-server-2014

Comment: Thanks. but i figure it out, it was the avast antivirus, when i disable self defense feature, installation completed without issues.

Comment: Antivirus, gets us all the time! :-)